# matplotlib savefig trims the graph

Tags: python, charts, matplotlib

I have a pretty simple pie chart in `pyplot`. The relevant code is this:

```
labels = 'SLoC', 'Violation'
sizes = [nrOfLines-totviols, totviols]
colors = ['#005fab', 'lightcoral']
explode = (0, 0.1)
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True,  startangle=90)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.savefig("/usr/share/scaweb/static/plot-ratio.png", transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

In the picture, the pie chart is trimmed, which is wierd as the labels outside of the chart are still fully visible:

[image: Trimmed pie chart]

I'm using `matplotlib` version 1.2.

Comment: is the graph trimmed also if you don't use `bbox_inches='tight'`?

Comment: yes. it affects the space around the entire graph (including labels and all). if I remove it, there will be a white border all around the image, even at the bottom, while the bottom of the circle still remains trimmed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the circle is extending past the edges of the (axes that you can not see, but are there as the library sees the figure) and hence is getting clipped.  This:

```
[__.set_clip_on(False) for __ in plt.gca().get_children()]
```

should fix it, but you might want to report this as a bug.